# Proof that this set is convex set

Tags: proof-writing

I need a help with prooving that a given set is a convex set:
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, c \in \mathbb{R}^n , b\in \mathbb{R}^m:$
$? \in argmin\{ c^Tx| Ax=b,x \geq 0\}$

I know the definition of convexity: $S \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set if $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \leq\lambda \leq 1$ and $\forall x_1,x_2 \in S$ holds: $\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda)x_2 \in S$.

I tried to apply this for my set but I dont know how to prove that it works... Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: You need to define your set properly for anyone to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=\min\{c^Tx:Ax=b\}$
Given $x_1\in S$, $x_2\in S$, we know $Ax_1=b,Ax_2=b,c^Tx_1=d,c^Tx_2=d$.
Calculate $A(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)$ and $c^T(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)$.
Conclude that $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2\in S$ as well.

Comment: +1 (but this would be even better without the (unnecessary) arrows on top of some vectors but not of all).